# Why does "yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame()" never returns in batchmode?

Tags: testing, unity-game-engine, integration-testing

I am trying to write integration tests by using unity test tools package.

Tests run without problem in the editor (in play mode).

But when I try to run the integration test from the command line (in batchmode) **WaitForEndOfFrame** coroutine never returns.

Is this a known issue or am I missing something?

I am using the below command to run the tests:

```
 /Applications/Unity-5.3.1-f1/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity \
  -batchmode \
  -nographics \
  -logfile \
  -projectPath $(pwd) \
  -executeMethod UnityTest.Batch.RunIntegrationTests \
  -testscenes=TestScene \
  -resultsFileDirectory=$(pwd)
```

Comment: Seems like a bug: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/yield-waitforendofframe-never-happens-in-batchmode Here's some code that (supposedly) fixes the issue for integration test usage: https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/unitytesttools/pull-requests/33/workaround-for-issue-with/diff

Comment: Ah - there's now somewhere in the doco. that simply states it does not work in batchmode.   Can't google it just now, but remember reading that recently.

Answer (score 1):

Unity doesn't update frames in the Editor when in Batch Mode. From their [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CLIBatchmodeCoroutines.html):

> - You cannot use **WaitForEndOfFrame** when running the Editor with -batchmode, because systems like animation, physics and timeline
>     might not work correctly in the Editor. This is because Unity does not currently update these systems when using WaitForEndOfFrame.

Answer (score -3):

If you're using C#, it won't work. If you use JS it will. For C# you need to use Coroutine, IEnumerable for this.

Same as Yielding call for Time WaitForSeconds and Etc. They don't support Yielding for C# cause Mono Unity3d only runs on the MainThread and cannot be yield cause you will get App is not Responding. On the other hand while JS is working, it is not exactly stopping the calls, it is stopping its own script. That is why invoke method is added for C# for delaying.

Comment: The question is asking why `WaitForEndOfFrame` doesn't work as expected in batchmode. This answer doesn't answer that question at all.